# How to deal with inconsistent pulp solution depending on specific inputs?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have set a small script that describes a diet optimization solution in pulp. The particular integers are not really relevant, they are just macros from foods. The strange thing is that when one of protein_ratio, carb_ratio or fat_ratio is 0.1, then the problem becomes infeasible. For other combinations of these factors (**which always should add up to 1**) the problem has a solution. Is there any way to sort of relax the objective function so that the solution might have a small error margin? For example instead of giving you the grams that will lead to a 800 calorie meal, it would give you the grams that lead to a 810 calorie meal. This would still be acceptable. Here is the script:

```
from pulp import *

target_calories = 1500

protein_ratio = 0.4 #play around with this - 0.1 breaks it
carb_ratio = 0.4 #play around with this - 0.1 breaks it
fat_ratio = 0.2 #play around with this - 0.1 breaks it

problem = LpProblem("diet", sense = LpMinimize)
gramsOfMeat = LpVariable("gramsOfMeat", lowBound = 1)
gramsOfPasta = LpVariable("gramsOfPasta", lowBound = 1 )
gramsOfOil = LpVariable("gramsOfOil", lowBound = 1)

problem += gramsOfMeat*1.29 + gramsOfPasta*3.655 + gramsOfOil*9 - target_calories

totalprotein = gramsOfMeat*0.21 + gramsOfPasta*0.13 + gramsOfOil*0
totalcarb = gramsOfMeat*0 + gramsOfPasta*0.75 + gramsOfOil*0
totalfat = gramsOfMeat*0.05 + gramsOfPasta*0.015 + gramsOfOil*1
totalmacros = totalprotein + totalcarb + totalfat

problem += totalfat== fat_ratio*totalmacros
problem += totalcarb == carb_ratio*totalmacros
problem += totalprotein == protein_ratio*totalmacros



problem += gramsOfMeat*1.29 + gramsOfPasta*3.655 + gramsOfOil*9 - target_calories == 0

status = problem.solve()
print(status)
#assert status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
#print(totalmacros)
print("Grams of meat: {}, grams of pasta: {}, grams of oil: {}, error: {}".format(value(gramsOfMeat), value(gramsOfPasta), value(gramsOfOil), value(problem.objective)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a penalty for violating the target. The idea would be to introduce two new decision variables, say `under` and `over`, and add constraints that say

```
problem += gramsOfMeat*1.29 + gramsOfPasta*3.655 + gramsOfOil*9 - target_calories <= under
problem += target_calories - (gramsOfMeat*1.29 + gramsOfPasta*3.655 + gramsOfOil*9) <= over
```

Then change your objective function to something like

```
problem += c_under * under + c_over * over
```

where `c_under` is the penalty per unit for being under the target and `c_over` is the penalty for being over. (These are parameters.) If you want to impose a hard bound on the over/under, you can add new constraints:

```
problem += under <= max_under
problem += over <= max_over
```

where `max_under` and `max_over` are the maximum allowable deviations (again, parameters).

One note: Your model is a little weird because it doesn't really have an objective function. Normally in the diet problem you want to minimize cost or maximize calories or something like that, and in general in linear programming you want to minimize or maximize something. In your model, you only have constraints. True, there is something that looks like an objective function --

```
problem += gramsOfMeat*1.29 + gramsOfPasta*3.655 + gramsOfOil*9 - target_calories
```

-- but since you have constrained this to equal 0, it doesn't really have any effect. There's certainly nothing *incorrect* about not having an objective function, but it's unusual, and I wanted to mention it in case this is not what you intended.

Comment: By the way, there's an effort to start a Stack Exchange site on Operations Research -- you can check it out and "commit" to it [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research) if you are interested.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have a question about your comment on the objective function. If I solve this in Excel solver, I simply enter the same formula and set target EQUAL to target_calories. For example, I would want a combination of grams of meat, pasta and olive oil to result in 800 calories (given certain macro ratio constraints). But, in pulp, there is not EQUAL for the objective function, and thus I looked around on stackoverflow and saw that I must first assign the problem and then force the equality through a constraint. What is wrong with this logic? Thank you

Comment: Oh, there's nothing *wrong* with that logic. It's just not the typical way optimization is used, though it's not unheard of. In that case you have what's called a "feasibility problem" -- all you need is to satisfy the constraints, and there's no objective function. An easier way to do what you did is just to say "minimize 0" as your objective -- `problem += 0`. Then every feasible solution is equally good. You basically did the same thing, you just had a more complicated expression that means "0" because of your constraint.

Comment: Maybe the source of confusion is that Excel's feature is a little redundant. If you want to set a certain cell equal to a certain value, you can use the "set equal to" button for the objective function, *or* you can set it equal to that value in a constraint. You chose the former way, and that translated to your `pulp` implementation, but the latter way is the more typical.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will play around with your recommendations. Thanks again!